# Google web font displaying incorrect weight on initial page load

Tags: css, fonts

I am using a Google web font, linked like this in the "head" section of my website:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,600,700">
```

My client is using Safari and is reporting the following behavior:

1. When the page first loads, fonts which are set to "font-weight:300"
   are displaying bolder than they should.
2. When the browser window is reduced and rescaled, it cleans itself
       up, and the font appears at the correct weight.

What would cause the initial state? Possibly the page loaded faster than the three weights (300,600,700) could download from Google?

Would appreciate any insight as to how external fonts load with relation to local CSS, etc.

Comment: what is the default font-weight in your css?

Comment: I guess I don't have one, I just have it specified directly on the H1 tag. Do you mean that I should specify it on the body tag, or elsewhere in the CSS?

Comment: If it is altering the weight on your p tags etc, it could be worth setting the default weight to 300 (or whichever) in your css to see if that helps - I can't really troubleshoot further without seeing the problem in action

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "setting the default weight"? Does that mean in the body tag, or something else?

Comment: Oh sorry, sure - you could add into your paragraph declaration (or the effected declarations) for example p {font-size: 16px etc etc *and* font-weight: 300;} within this rule.

Comment: Hang on sorry- you said you have it declared on the affected h1 tag - have you been able to duplicate the behaviour? it could be something to do with your clients own browser settings

Comment: I haven't been able to duplicate the behavior, it might be the browser, although I don't know what "setting" would cause the exact behavior as I'm describing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76192/discussion-between-anniemac-and-bb-design).

Answer (score 1):

The default font weight, when not explicitly specified in your CSS, is 400 (with alias "normal"), but the font you're loading does not have a weight-400 variant (only 300, 600, and 700). As such, any element that makes use of this font in its CSS rules will also need  to explicit set `font-weight: 300` (or 600 or 700) to ensure the correct weight variant is used.

(The rules for which weight is selected in the absence of a font weight is documented in the [CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness), starting at "missing weights are selected as follows", so it might even be that safari has a font weight lookup bug here)